# Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div> next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using nextjs to build a web app and an hydration error appeared suddenly from nowhere without any code modification, I've searched everywhere tried everything but the error won't go :(

Here is the error I get :

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:240:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:315:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:130:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:151:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:226:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:325:11)
    at RehydrationContextProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/dist/ssr/RehydrationContext.js:15:39)
    at ApolloProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@apollo/client/react/context/ApolloProvider.js:14:21)
    at ApolloNextAppProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/dist/ssr/ApolloNextAppProvider.js:45:11)
    at ApolloWrapper (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/lib/apollo-client.tsx:41:11)
    at SWRConfig (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/swr/_internal/dist/index.mjs:571:13)
    at SessionProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:455:24)
    at Providers (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/providers.tsx:15:11)
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:11)
    at DevRootNotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:295:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:159:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:100:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:130:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:436:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:128:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:144:11)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
    at throwOnHydrationMismatch (react-dom.development.js:7076:9)
    at tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance (react-dom.development.js:7121:7)
    at updateHostComponent$1 (react-dom.development.js:16503:5)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18390:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:20461:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (react-dom.development.js:20510:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:20585:29)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26763:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25587:12)
    at workLoopConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:25573:5)
    at renderRootConcurrent (react-dom.development.js:25529:9)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24382:38)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:21)
```

I tried setting some components to ssr: false, checking the entire dom to look for forbidden nested tags, etc...

I'm new with SSR and I can't find any solution to this, if anyone could help me that would be amazing !
Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

My bad it was due to my Arc browser boosts that adds html code to the current page, stupid mistake !